# Unix Find directories containing more than 2 files

Tags: unix, csh

I have a directory containing over a thousand subdirectories. I only want to 'ls' all the directories that contain more than 2 files. I don't need the directories that contain less than 2 files. This is in C-shell, not bash. Anyone know of a good command for this?

I tried this command but it's not giving the desired output. I simply want the full list of directories with more than 2 files. A reason it isn't working is because it will go into sub dirs in those dirs to find if they have more than 2 files. I don't want a recursive search. Just a list of first level directories in the main directory they are in.

`$ find . -type f -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 2'`

Comment: I would use `find . -d` to find and print directories.  I would pipe it into a loop which did `ls -1` on each directory it found and piped that into `wc -l` and captured the output in a variable.  Then I could test the variable and, if greater than 2, I would rerun `ls` on the the directory again, without redirecting the output.  To limit the search to top-level directories, I would add `-depth -2` to the `find` command.  But I not a csh programmer, so I can't show you how to write the loop in csh.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was thinking bash rather than csh. Although I don't have a csh to test with, I think this is the csh syntax for the same thing:

```
foreach d (*)
  if (d "$d" && `ls -1 "$d"|wc -l` > 2) echo "$d"
end
```

I've added a guard so that non-directories aren't unnecessarily processed, and I've included double-quotes in case there are any "funny" file or directory names (containing spaces e.g.).

One possible problem (I don't know what your exact task is): any immediate subdirectories will also count as files.

Sorry, I was working in bash here:

`for d in *;do if [ $(ls -1 $d|wc -l) -gt 2 ];then echo $d;fi;done`

For a faster solution, you could try "cheating" by deconstructing the format of the directories themselves if you're on pure Unix. They're just files themselves with contents that can be analyzed in that case. Needless to say that is NOT PORTABLE, to e.g. any bash running on Windows, so not recommended.

Comment: When I try this, it gives me an error for illegal variable name. Could it be due to syntax error for C-shell?

Comment: @JeffY : Although the OP tagged the question as `Shell`, he explicitly expressed his wish to see a csh solution, for whatever reason.